# Smooth movement when the browser window resizes, between centered element, and absolute/fixed element

Tags: css

I have a `wrapper`, and in the `wrapper` there is the `header` and the `body`, which are center  horizontal.

To the right I have `wrapper-right` which is fixed to the browser right.

When the browser window becomes smaller(lower resolution), I want the `wrapper-right` to get closer to the `header` until a minimal distance between them.

When the minimal distance is met, I want the `header` to change size(become smaller), but keep the minimal distance. also I want the header to remain align left to 'body' (being smaller than body now, center is not ok)

At this moment my implementation is using media queries (3-4, just 1 in example), but it is not smooth, so I'm searching for something better.

```css
.wrapper{
  background-color:green;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.header, body{ 
  max-width: 30rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header { 
  border:3px solid yellow;
  max-width: 30rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border-left: 5px solid purple;
  }
@media (max-width: 40rem){
   .header{
    max-width: 25rem;
    }
  }


.body{
  background-color:red;
  height: 500px;
  border-left: 5px solid purple;
}
.wrapper-right{
    background: #0069aa;
    height: 4rem;
    width: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <span> header header </span>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <span> body body </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-right"> 
  <span> ipsum ipsum right </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a width equal to `width: calc(100vw - 10rem - X);` where `X` is the distance you want to keep (`10rem` is twice the size of the fixed element) and your element will behave as expected when the fixed element will get close:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4rem;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.header,
body {
  max-width: 30rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  max-width: 30rem;
  height: 4rem;
  width: calc(100vw - 10rem - 2rem);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  background-color: red;
  height: 500px;
}

.wrapper-right {
  background: #0069aa;
  height: 4rem;
  width: 5rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <span> header header </span>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <span> body body </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-right">
  <span> ipsum ipsum right </span>
</div>
```

Comment: the header doesn't remain aligned with body, left, see left yellow border and body in red

Comment: @user3541631 you can then do the same to the body by applying the same width ;)

Comment: @user3541631 Oh  wait, you mean that the right should decrease but not the left?

Comment: header must remained aligned left with body. Body is always centered in the browser window, and never change the size. Only header change the size to accommodate wrapper-right. | In the answer the header which starts centered, remains centered. And I don't want that I want to remain aligned left to the body. I made a purple border to understand what I want to remain aligned.